# Microsoft Azure Stream analytics and blob storage input

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob storage where I store data from event hub using routes. 
I want to display that data, for example in PowerBI, or put it in a topic etc.

For that I create a stream analytics job. I set "Blob storage" as an input, and one of my topics as an output.

I wrote a very basic SQL

```
SELECT
    * INTO
    [sajoutputtopic] FROM
    [blobstoragesajinput]
```

Then I send message to IoT Hub:
*{"deviceId":"mydevice","messageId":921,"temperature":31,"humidity":72}*

In azure I can see that is stored in blob
Then I test the SQL:

1. download blob
2. right click on the input -> "upload sample data from file", select "AVRO"

but when I click test, I get 0 rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what is the problem: the data are not in blob storage or you cant access it from stream analitycs ?

Comment: @Thomas the data is in blob storage, but I can't get and push to stream analytics output (SELECT always returns 0 rows)

Answer (score 0):

amplifier. You need to check the file format you downloaded. It need to be matched with the selected option. I created json file which stores your sample data. Then I right clicked on the input -> "upload sample data from file", select "JSON". It works fine.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that blobs are not JSONs. They are in AVRO format. JSON format works for me as well.